# How to create exact copy of protected DVD?

Tags: video, conversion, mkv

First the explanation: I just bought some workout DVDs. My wife and I have a room in our house where we exercise, but my wife also works out with friends she dances with at her studio. I'd like to work out at home, and she'd like to be able to work out at her studio.

We could swap DVDs and try not to do the same workouts on the same days, but it would be easier if I could just copy the DVDs and she could just have those to herself. So my question is, how can I create an exact copy of the DVDs, complete with title menus, etc? I want the experience to be the exact same from the originals to the copies.

I've found a bunch of articles on this through Google, but they all seem to be centered on ripping. Furthermore, the few articles I've found about actually copying never mention whether the entire DVD will be copied (title menus, etc.. everything the same) or just the primary title (like the movie, but not extra features, etc.). I've messed around some with MakeMKV, and it seems to have ripped all the titles ok, but I don't know how to reconstruct them back into the original DVD.

I'm willing to pay for software that can do it. I really just need to know if this is possible, particularly with encrypted, protected DVDs.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't mind paying for software, why do you mind paying for two legitimate copies, or otherwise 'playing by the rules' by using the DVDs in only one place at a time? It seems to me that asking this question is tantamount to asking 'how can I cheat the author?'. Is this the sort of question we want here?

Comment: This site is for Video Production, not consumer consumption concerns.  Additionally, asking how to bypass copy protection on a Q/A site dedicated to Audio/Video Production (aka content producers) probably isn't the best place to ask where to rip off content.  It's a bit like walking in to a police station and asking how to rob a bank.

Comment: My mistake: I was under the impression this site was a Q&A site for those that needed help with tasks related to video production; things like copying DVDs (by definition, producing new video). Because this was an honest, fair, and legal concern of mine, I'm surprised and disappointed at the backlash. You're entitled to your opinion, but when it encroaches on a Q&A process that, by all intentions, should be allowed, you've hindered that process and degraded the experience for other users on the site. Anyway, I got my answer despite the criticism, and I'll use that answer for legal purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't seem to want to make any changes, just rip the whole DVD to an ISO image and then burn that to blank media. I recommend [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/).

Comment: [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System) will prevent a byte for byte copy working without some additional work.  ImgBurn will detect the CSS and refuse to copy the disk.

Comment: Because I have a Mac, I used Mac DVD Ripper Pro to rip the DVDs to ISO files, and OSX's built-in Disk Utility to then burn those images to each disc's respective copy.